# ActiveAdmin renders datatype text as textarea in its forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

My model consists of a couple rows with datatype `text`. Unfortunately [ActiveAdmin](http://activeadmin.info/) seem to render these as a `<textarea>`. I would like to have them as an `<input type="text">` but I cannot make it to work. My attempt so far:

```
form do |f|
  inputs do
    f.input :name, as: :text
    f.input :name, input_html: { type: "text" }
  end 
end
```

Any idea how I can render datatype `text` row as a standard input, not as a textarea in ActiveAdmin?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
form do |f|
  inputs do
    f.input :name, as: :string
  end
end
```

Comment: this worked, thank you! It's a shame I couldn't find it in the ActiveAdmin docs.